# Can't get A record redirect to work properly

Tags: domain-name-system, https, http, cloudflare

Okay.. this should be a pretty simple fix but nothing is working, maybe I'm missing something:

A record is set for my blog, sample site here: http://43.130.149.65/?rid=yLmTQxP Cloudflare set for an A record from 43.130.149.65 > cbwg.blog ( with both @ and www set)

I only have port 80 working on the server, since I'm trying to get CloudFlare to issue my cert.

I can browse directly to the site but going through CloudFlare is throwing a 521 error.

The site accepts all connections on port 80. What am I missing?

I am using the "Flexible" setting in CloudFlare. I expect the website to be served via SSL.

I have tried tcpdump on the server and the requests aren't even hitting the endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your settings have not yet propagated through Cloudflare.

```
> nslookup cbwg.blog 8.8.8.8
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    cbwg.blog
Addresses:  2606:4700:3030::ac43:930d
          2606:4700:3034::6815:1cb2
          104.21.28.178
          172.67.147.13
```

You do have Cloudflare set properly as your NS - `nslookup -type=ns` does show two Cloudflare servers as authoritative DNS - so you probably will have to contact Cloudflare for assistance with this.

Edit: `www.cbwg.blog` does resolve, but your server is refusing connections to that address. Is your web server set to accept connections to that variant of the name?

Comment: Yeah that looks like it was correct.. just had to wait and everything magically worked - thanks!